# jquery div hidden and show, how to control show div's position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make an easy div hover show and hide `introduce words` with jQuery,  in the default code. All the introduced words position is relative. the `introduce words` div's of `box4` and `box8` will out of the `div#main`.

and how to do? so that the introduce words div of `box4` and `box8` will make a right align?

For I can not describe well in english, I make a picture. you can see when hover in `box4`, the `introduce words` div's right will not out of the `div#main`, this is what I need. Thanks.

code link here: http://jsfiddle.net/KTGUz/

image: [image: what I want like this]

Comment: this will sure helps u : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214781/recalculating-tooltip-position-on-browser-window-resize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure jQuery way is `$('.box:nth-child(4n+4)').addClass('oy');` and adjust your positioning to make the `.box` relative and the `.hover` absolute, making `.oy {right: 0;}`

Here's the stuff: http://jsfiddle.net/3jGdm/

Answer (score 1):

You could give boxes 4 and 8 a different class if you know they're going to always be on the edge. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/M687z/

Answer (score 0):

If it depends on the window width how many boxes are in a row you can use the jQuery.offset() feature to reposition the title_box if it would overflow:

http://api.jquery.com/offset/