# jquery div hidden and show, z-index issue and mouseover/mouseout issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made an easy div hover control, show and hidden introduce words with jquery.

I have already ask a question in [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138732/jquery-div-hidden-and-show-how-to-control-show-divs-position)

@Steve Perks and @patorjk answered me. Thanks both of them.

But now, I still have some more questions.

1. the index problem in IE. how to make `div.hover` on the top level?
2. If I add some hyper link in the `div.hover`, how to modify js code, so that only mouse out both `div.hover` and `div.title`, `div.hover` would hidden (I need click the link)

Thanks a lot.

---

I updated my code here http://jsfiddle.net/3jGdm/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="main">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="title">1</div>
            <div class="hover">this is number 1, when you hover to the box content, show <a href="">something</a> here.</div>
            <p>Box 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="title">2</div>
            <div class="hover">this is number 1, when you hover to the box content, show <a href="">something</a> here.</div>
            <p>Box 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="title">3</div>
            <div class="hover">this is number 1, when you hover to the box content, show <a href="">something</a> here.</div>
            <p>Box 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="title">4</div>
            <div class="hover">this is number 1, when you hover to the box content, show <a href="">something</a> here.</div>
            <p>Box 4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="title">5</div>
            <div class="hover">this is number 1, when you hover to the box content, show <a href="">something</a> here.</div>
            <p>Box 5</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="title">6</div>
            <div class="hover">this is number 1, when you hover to the box content, show <a href="">something</a> here.</div>
            <p>Box 6</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="title">7</div>
            <div class="hover">this is number 1, when you hover to the box content, show <a href="">something</a> here.</div>
            <p>Box 7</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="title">8</div>
            <div class="hover">this is number 1, when you hover to the box content, show <a href="">something</a> here.</div>
            <p>Box 8</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;}
#body{width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#fff;}
#main{width:800px;height:400px;margin:0 auto;background-color:#999;}
.box{float:left;width:180px;height:150px;margin:9px;border:1px solid #666;display:inline-block;position:relative;}
.title{font-size:32px;line-height:150px;text-align:center;}
.hover{display:none;position:absolute;width:300px;background-color:#9C9;border:1px solid #666;z-index:10;font-size: 16px;}
.oy .hover{right:0;}
p{text-align:center;background-color:#333;}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box:nth-child(4n+4)').addClass('oy');
    $(".title").mouseover(
    function () {
      $(this).parent('.box').children(".hover").show();
    }), 
    $(".title").mouseout(
    function () {
      $(this).parent('.box').children(".hover").hide();
    }
);
});
```

Comment: Which version(s) of Internet Explorer exhibit `"the index problem"`?

Comment: @thirtydot, Adam Lamer have answered one, works in ie8, but not in ie6, do you have any good idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It seems to be working alright, but this code would guarantee it's on top:

```
$('div.hover').css('z-index', '1000');
```

2) You would just add a mouseover and mouseout function for the hover divs as well:

```
$('div.hover').mouseover(
    function(){
        $(this).show();
    }
);
$('div.hover').mouseout(
    function(){
        $(this).hide();
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3jGdm/6/

Comment: thanks. works in ie8, but not in ie6... any other advice? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, from what I can find it looks like Bjorn's solution should work for the index. A merge of his index fix and my mouseover functionality should get the job done. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: yeah, i tested their code, but `the 4th,8th .hover` position become right of the screen, not right of the `4th,8th .box`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to fix the z-index issue in IE, you need to apply a z-index to the `.box` container when active or hovered.

See http://jsfiddle.net/3jGdm/7/ for an example.

**Updated js:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box:nth-child(4n+4)').addClass('oy');
    $(".title").mouseover(

    function() {
        $(this).parent('.box').addClass("indexFix").children(".hover").show();
    }), $(".title").mouseout(

    function() {
        $(this).parent('.box').removeClass("indexFix").children(".hover").hide();
    });
});
```

**Note the updated class:**

```
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 9px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    }
```

**And the new class:**

```
.indexFix {
    z-index: 10;
    }
```

Comment: this can fix the index problem. but `the 4th,8th .hover` position become `right of the screen`, not right of `the 4th,8th .box`.thanks.

Comment: You need to add `position:relative` to `.box` and set your hover `left:0px`. See here: [http://jsfiddle.net/3jGdm/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/3jGdm/9/).